# ICMP echo-reply not received when going through scapy

Tags: python, scapy, icmp

Here's the screenshot of a wireshark screenshot of the echo request received by H2

[image: Here's the screenshot of a wireshark screenshot of the echo request received by H2]

I'm still learning scapy and my topology is like this:
H1---S1---H3---S2---H2.... Here, I'm trying to send a ping request from H1 to H2 by going through H3. I'm running the scapy code given in H3. When i try to ping H2 from H1.. H2 does receive the echo-request but H2 doesn't give echo-reply... What could be the reason?

```
from scapy.all import *

def handlePacket(pkt):
    if pkt.sniffed_on == "h3-eth0":
        if IP in pkt and ICMP in pkt:
            if pkt[IP].src==h1IPAddress and pkt[IP].dst == h2IPAddress:
                sendp(pkt,iface="h3-eth1")
    elif pkt.sniffed_on == "h3-eth1":
        if IP in pkt and ICMP in pkt:
            if pkt[IP].src==h2IPAddress and pkt[IP].dst==h1IPAddress:
                sendp(pkt,iface="h3-eth0")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sniff(filter="icmp",iface=["h3-eth0","h3-eth1"],prn=handlePacket)
```

Comment: Can you post a wireshark screenshot of the echo request received by H2?

Comment: I wonder if it's not because the MAC destination address in the echo request forwarded by H3 to H2 is the one of H3.  Therefore H2 ignores it.

Comment: @qouify Yes actually.. You're correct.. The destination MAC address is of H3.. I guess that is the problem i forgot to look at.

Comment: @qouify Thank you very much for pointing it out. It is working now.